# How to build interactive menu for command-line application in python?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

I've been working with [click](http://click.pocoo.org/) to make a command line program. Right now I'm implementing interactive menus in a very textual way. for example:

```
1-option #1
2-option #2
Enter the index of the option you want to select:
```

But I would love to do this in a more elegant and interactive way. For example, I love the way Yeoman implements its menus. Here is the menu in action.
[image]

Is there any python library that let's us build command line menus like this? I have looked at libraries like curses, cmd etc. But they seem to give you a whole separate window to manage and look kind of unpythonic.

Comment: Interesting question, but unfortunately off-topic (I think). The question might be better suited for [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: Not work on python2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`curses`, or something like it, really is what you want.

While `curses` can be used to pop up "windows" with borders around them, erase the whole window, etc., at its base, what it's about is giving you control over your terminal window—moving a cursor around, highlighting text, all the other things you're trying to do.

Some of the higher-level libraries that make things easier (like `urwid`) do push you toward a more specific look & feel that may not be what you're after, but `curses` can easily be used for exactly what you're trying to build.

The only real problem with `curses` it's that it's not ubiquitous. Almost all *nix platforms will have it, but Windows won't. But the answer there isn't much different—there are `curses`-faking libraries, or Windows-specific `conio` libraries (including a limited one in the stdlib, inside `mscvrt`).

Comment: This seems like more painful than it should be. Requiring multiple different libraries for different platforms is not something I want to do for now. I guess I will stick with my text based menus for now.
Thanks for the answer anyway. :)

Comment: @tarashish: You can actually build the Python `curses` module on Windows against one of a couple of `libcurses` ports. You can't normally expect end-users to do that, but if your goal is to build a binary executable for Windows, that might be reasonable. As a different alternative, I believe there are some wrappers that provide either a `conio`-like subset of functionality that works on both platforms (whether wrapping `curses`, or doing `termcap` and `tcsetattr` stuff manually, on *nix), but I haven't used any of them.