# Push text from bottom edge of console?

Tags: python, windows-console

I am making a Python program, and I was wondering if I was able to push the text from the bottom edge of the console screen. I want there to be some blank space between the bottom of the screen and the last line printed, just to make it look nicer.

[image]

As you can see in the picture, the text is right at the bottom of the screen. Unfortunately, I can't fix this problem by adding a \n as this would also move the user input to the new line.

How do I add a space without moving the user input?

This is how the code is currently formatted:

```
print("")
print("    Would you like to shoot your Arrow(A), move North(N), East(E), South(S)")
action=input("                            or West(W), or Quit(Q)? ")
```

Comment: The formatting capabilites depend on the shell. What are you using to format the output currently? Show some code! Maybe [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html) can give you some pointers.

Comment: I have added the last few lines of code.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25227519/how-to-build-interactive-menu-for-command-line-application-in-python

Comment: I had a look at curses but couldn't find anything that suited my question.

Comment: You could print two lines and then move the cursor up a line. Are you using colorama for writing text in color? If so, it supports codes for positioning the cursor, e.g. `ESC [ n A` to move up n lines.

Comment: Further [info on CMD buffers](https://www.burgaud.com/bring-colors-to-the-windows-console-with-python/).

Comment: good old wumpus. Glad to hear it's still alive. Had good times with it decades ago...

Comment: That would be https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama

Comment: Python's `StandardOutput` is not a CMD screen buffer. That's like confusing bash with an X terminal in Linux. cmd.exe has the same relationship to the console (an instance of conhost.exe) as python.exe, powershell.exe, doskey.exe, chcp.com, mode.com, etc. These executables are flagged in their image header to automatically attach to a console, either the parent's console or a new one (if they aren't run as a detached process). Windows applications without this flag (e.g. pythonw.exe) have to do this manually via `AttachConsole` or `AllocConsole`.